# Clarity on Covariance Matrix and it's relation to length

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, pca, covariance, covariance-matrix

I have been trying hard since a month to get a clear intuition on the relation of the covariance matrix to length of projections(maximum or otherwise). While I understand conceptually that if I have a data matrix $A$ of size $[N,2]$ and I want to project these onto some vector $x$ of size $[2,1]$ then $Ax$ will give me a list of projections for each data point in $A$.

Now we say we want to maximise the variance of these projections which is equivalent to maximising the length of $Ax$ so we want to $max((Ax)^T(Ax))$ with respect to $x$. I understand things clearly upto this point.

Rewriting of this as $max(x^T(A^TA)x)$ starts to trouble me a bit.

Say $e$ is the vector that maximises this. I would like to interpret what happens to $e$ step by step here. First we $Ae$ will project $e$ into the space of $A$. Then $A^T(Ae)$ will get the projection lengths of this vector to the basis vectors in $A$. And finally $x^T(A^TAx) $ will take a linear combination of these lengths to give the final output. I don't see clearly how the last two steps should be interpreted as giving length. I understand on the whole conceptually but not how it works in the tiny details as above.

I would also like to know where co-variance plays a role in the above way of looking at things. (I understand $A^TA$ is the covariance matrix but where does it appear in length calculations.

Comment: The $e$ vector is usually a unit vector in order to scale appropriately. To recover the scaling in A this is then multiplied by a scalar (in eigen decomposition this will be the eigenvalue). A key benefit is that a scalar can be easily inverted for the inverse operation to multiplication.

Comment: $A^\prime A$ is a covariance matrix only when its columns have means of zero.  That would seem to contradict the information you see clearly, so you might want to revisit your assumptions.

Comment: @whuber Right, lets say it is normalised, I am just looking for a step-by step interpretation of $x^T(A^TA)x$. What would it be then?

Comment: Because $$x^\prime (A^\prime A) x = (Ax)^\prime\, (Ax) = |Ax|^2,$$ a good interpretation is that it's the squared Euclidean length of $Ax.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're okay with $max((Ax)^T(Ax))$ but not $max(x^T(A^TA)x)$.

You may already know that we can get equivalence between these by just applying a few basic rules of matrix algebra -- transpose of product, and associativity:

$$(Ax)^T(Ax) = (x^TA^T)(Ax) = x^TA^TAx = x^T(A^TA)x.$$

Even if you already know this you may want different ways to interpret the expression depending on where we put the parentheses.  I get that.  It might be useful to try to gain intuition for matrix associativity beyond simple algebraic proofs in a more general context than statistical matrices.  But I can try to talk about the statistical interpretations.

For this to apply to covariance matrices and maximizing variance, then $A$ has to be centered.

Let

$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 & z_1 \\
x_2 & y_2 & z_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
x_n & y_n & z_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$

We have $n$ samples / data points / whatever, and each one is a 3-dimensional (row) vector. The matrix shape is n-by-3.

### connection betwen variance and length

There are actually two lengths of interest here -- the length of our data points (their distance from the origin) in the 3-dimensional row world, and the "length" of each variable in the n-dimensional column world.

Each sample (row), like $r_1 = \left[x_1\;y_1\;z_1\right]$, has a length (the point's distance from the origin):

$$\|r_1\| = \sqrt{\left<r_1, r_1\right>}  = \sqrt{x_1^2 + y_1^2 + z_1^2}$$

At the same time, the column vector corresponding to just one of our variables (one dimension of our samples)

$$X = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
\vdots \\
x_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$

has a length.  First, consider the squared length:

$$X^TX = x_1^2 + \dots + x_n^2$$.

This should look reminiscent of $Var(X)$. Recall,

$Var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2.$

Since $A$ is centered (the columns have sum/mean zero), $E(X)^2 = 0$. The only thing missing is dividing by $n$ to get a mean instead of a sum .  So

$$Var(X) = \frac{X^TX}{n} \propto X^TX = \|X\|^2$$

and, for fun,

$$stdev(X) = \frac{\|X\|}{\sqrt{n}}$$

So we can basically ignore normalizing by $n$ and more or less picture $Var(X)$ as the squared length of the vector $X$.  Maximizing one is equivalent to maximizing the other since $n$ is constant.  Remember, this only works because $A$ is centered.

Let's introduce a unit vector $u$.  Using the basic definition of matrix multiplication, and recalling that we've named the $ith$ row of $A$ (the $ith$ data point) $r_i$,

$$Au = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\left<r_1, u\right>\\
\vdots \\
\left<r_n, u\right>\\
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
p_1 \\
\vdots \\
p_n
\end{bmatrix} = P
$$

Let's look at the lengths in the two worlds again.

$Au$ is an n-by-1 matrix.  We've also named this result $P$. The rows are 1-dimensional.  Keep in mind the difference between the projection of one vector onto another, which is a vector in the original 3-d space, and the (signed) length / magnitude of that projection, which is a scalar, or perhaps a 1-d vector.  When we say "project the rows of $A$ onto $u$", it can be ambiguous which we mean.  For now, we're interested in the latter.  Since $u$ is unit-length, $\left<r_i, u\right>$ is the (signed) length of the projection of $r_i$ onto $u$. It's 1-dimensional.  Think of this as a compressed version of our data.  Instead of a 3-d scatter plot (the $r$'s), we now have a 1-d scatter plot (the $p$'s).

Since they're 1-dimensional, computing row lengths is trivial: $\|p_i\| = \sqrt{\left<p_i, p_i\right>} = \sqrt{p_i^2} = p_i$

Hopefully it's not too confusing that I'm kind of using $p_i$ as both a 1-d vector and as a straight-up scalar real number there. Whereas before we had

$$r_i = \left[x_i\;y_i\;z_i\right]$$
we now are doing
$$p_i = \left[p_i\right]$$

which isn't great but maybe not worth the trouble to avoid.

In the same way that we considered the $p$'s to be our new data points, we can consider $P$ to be a new, single random variable, in place of $X$, $Y$, and $Z$.

Like before (since $P$ has zero mean again since its a linear combination of $X$, $Y$, and $Z$),

$$Var(P) \propto P^TP = p_0^2 + \dots + p_n^2$$

what's interesting here is that last expression.  Since $P$ is a vector whose entries are $p_i$, which are (trivially) the *lengths* of our new 1-d data points, $P^TP$ is the *sum* of the *squared* lengths of our 1-d data points. And so $Var(P)$ is basically (disregarding having to divide by $n$) the sum of the squared lengths of our data points.  More strictly, $Var(P)$ is the *average* of these squared lengths (sum, then divide by $n$). To be super explicit,

$$nVar(P) = \|P\|^2 = P^TP = p_0^2 + \dots + p_n^2 = \|p_0\|^2 + \dots + \|p_n\|^2$$

So that's the connection between variance and lengths.  Variance is conceptually very close the squared length of our column, which in the univariate case (1-dimensional data points), turns out to be the sum of the squared lengths of our data points.  Maximizing one or the other is equivalent.

### interpreting different sub-expressions of $u^TA^TAu$

$Au$ produces $P$, which is a set of 1-dimensional data points determined by the projection of the original points onto $u$.

Then, $A^T(Au)$ will be a 3-by-1 list of inner products of $P$ with each of $X$, $Y$, and $Z$.

$$A^T(Au) = 
A^TP =
\begin{bmatrix}
X^TP \\
Y^TP \\
Z^TP
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

In the same way that $Var(X) \propto X^TX$, try to work out for yourself that $Cov(X, P) \propto X^TP$ (when $X$ and $P$ have zero mean, which they do here).

Lastly,

$$u^T(A^T(Au)) = 
\begin{bmatrix}u_x & u_y & u_z\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
X^TP \\
Y^TP \\
Z^TP
\end{bmatrix} =
u_x (X^TP) + u_y (Y^TP) + u_z (Z^TP)
$$

You could try to think of this as projecting that vector of covariances of $P$ with the original 3 variables ($A^TAu$) onto $u$.  I don't think I've ever heard any one explicitly mention this interpretation even though it's pretty straightforward to arrive to, if not deeply grasp.  But ultimately,

$$
u_x (X^TP) + u_y (Y^TP) + u_z (Z^TP) = (u_xX + u_yY + u_zZ)^TP = P^TP = (Au)^T(Au)
$$

and that last expression is how most people interpret all of this --  the variance (not yet divided by $n$) of your new random variable $P$, which is its squared Euclidean length since $P$ is centered.

Some other useful resources in this area:

- [nice descriptions of PCA on stack exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2691)
- [3blue1brown video on dot product / projections](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LyGKycYT2v0)
- [Gilbert Strang lecture on projection, least squares (also covers the row and column view of data)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=osh80YCg_GM)

Comment: Thanks for great explanation. I understood perfectly till 'You could try to think of this as projecting that vector of covariances of P with the original 3 variables (ATAu) onto u.' Why do we want to do this? This step is not making sense to me

Comment: @RahulDeora, the reason we left-multiply (ATAu) by uT is because we have to add in that term to get the full (uT AT A u).  The comment about "thinking of this as projecting" is just an interpretation of this.  It's not a particularly useful interpretation and I don't yet have a better one.